# Python: how to use lambda or partial to bind arguments other than the first positional argument

Tags: python, lambda, arguments, partial

I am having a lot of confusion in trying to use either a `lambda` or `functools.partial` to create a new function with bound positional arguments from an existing function.

I want to do something like this (which is not behaving as desired):

```
def addFunction(self, name, in_function, secondary_args=None, secondary_kwargs=None):

        # Assign the function with optional args based on whether any
        # optional args are not None

        if secondary_args is not None and secondary_kwargs is not None:
            func = lambda x: in_function(x, *secondary_args, **secondary_kwargs)
        elif secondary_args is None and secondary_kwargs is not None:
            func = lambda x: in_function(x, **secondary_kwargs)
        elif secondary_args is not None and secondary_kwargs is None:
            func = lambda x: in_function(x, *secondary_args)
        else:
            func = in_function
        ###

        func.__doc__ = in_function.__doc__
        self[name] = func # <-- This method is a class method for something deriving dict.
```

I've also tried replacing all of the `lambda` statements with equivalent `functools.partial` statements.

The problem is that if I use this function like this:

```
# Assume some_function takes 3 arguments, a float, a Bool, and a String,
# in that order.

someObject.addFunction("my_f", some_function, secondary_args=[True, "Option_A"])
```

now when I try to use (just for example) `someObject["my_f"](5.0)` it reports the first argument is `True` when I debug it.

It seems like the bindings, either with `lambda` or with `partial` simply push in the positional arguments and either only accept your extra positional argument at the end of `*args` or else just are dropping it (I'm not sure which).

For my application, since lots of functions will be stored in a particular object like this, with varying numbers of optional arguments chosen by a user, it's important that the function I get back, with bound arguments, still accepts the user's argument as the first positional argument, without resorting to forcing all arguments to be key-word arguments.

This seems like it should be simple enough. What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you use keyword arguments exclusively?

Comment: Because the use case for this will be a bunch of folks writing scripts, where in each script they will write long lists of their own custom functions that they care about porting around with my object. I can't trust all of them to always make every function of theirs take keyword args only.

Comment: Or always allow for *args and **kwargs. If they're not used, they're not used.

Comment: Yes you can, if your function only accepts a dictionary, they have to abide by your rules.

Comment: The folks using it are not Python programmers; I'm pretty sure they'll tell me to change that restriction immediately regardless of pragmatic benefits to doing it.

Comment: But you can just bind it with keyword args as the internal args and then let them use whatever they want. You will always know yours are there as keywords

Comment: Doing this for their variable-number-of-args-functions seems silly. Would I just make arg names like "arg1" "arg2" etc, purely to have them as keywords and no other reason? That seems bad and might lose the "meaning" of their function, which they may intend to rely on the position of the arguments. I see that this would work, but it seems like a silly extra layer to add, when it should essentially be a 1-liner to get it to just not-bind the first positional argument.

Comment: The hacky work around I am using now is to give my own keyword to the common first argument, push that argument to the final argument, and just assume that they will be OK with have to have one keyword argument. Still, though, it feels like an unpythonic hack in either case.

Comment: Okay, then how do you want "the others" to be able to use these functions? Just make up some code that shows how they should be able to call the functions.

Comment: Apologies if I'm the only one not getting this, but I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you want to be patching new methods into a class at run-time, and at the same time potentially currying them?

Comment: Sort of like currying. I want users to be able to define custom sorting functions that always accept a data object as the first arg, and then whatever complicates sort-related stuff the user wants as the other args. Then I want to bind their extra args (leaving the first arg variable), put all those into a dictionary-type thing for them, and then the code I already have unpacks the dictionary-type object and auto-applies all of their sorting functions to the data, generating a bunch of results for them. It will always be used on the same type of data object, but their sorting functions...

Comment: can be arbitrarily complicated with whatever args they want to bind inside of their scripts (whatever matters to them when doing their experiments by sorting the data whatever way they want to define).

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a full script that reproduces the error? Because the following script works as expected:

```
class C(dict):                                                               
    def addFunction(self, name, in_function, secondary_args=None, secondary_kwargs=None):

        # Assign the function with optional args based on whether any        
        # optional args are not None                                         

        if secondary_args is not None and secondary_kwargs is not None:      
            func = lambda x, *secondary: in_function(x, *secondary_args, **secondary_kwargs)
        elif secondary_args is None and secondary_kwargs is not None:        
            func = lambda x: in_function(x, **secondary_kwargs)              
        elif secondary_args is not None and secondary_kwargs is None:        
            func = lambda x: in_function(x, *secondary_args)                 
        else:                                                                
            func = in_function                                               
        ###                                                                  

        func.__doc__ = in_function.__doc__                                   
        self[name] = func  # <-- This method is a class method for something deriving dict.


def f(x, y=0, z=1):                                                          
    print x, y, z                                                            


c = C()                                                                      
c.addFunction('my_f', f, secondary_args=[-1])                                
c['my_f'](0)                                                                 

# output is 0 -1 1, as expected
```

Maybe the problem is in how you "attach" the function to your object?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want some custom type of function wrapper:

```
class Caller(object):

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        self._fn = fn
        self._args = args 
        self._kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *uargs, **ukwargs):
        arg = uargs + self._args
        kw =  dict(ukwargs.items() + self._kwargs.items())
        self._fn(*arg, **kw)
```

And then to wrap something:

```
def test(a,b,c=None):
    print a,b,c

c = Caller(test, 2,c=True)
c(1)
# 1 2 True
```

I am sure that `Caller` could be cleaned up, but this was just a quick example of how to store the original fn and params, then have control over when it is being called.

Comment: This is not really what I am looking for. The users of my code are going to create scripts that contain functions used to sort on data objects. The data object should always be their first argument, but beyond that they will write functions however they want. I don't want to parse their arguments and wrap the function, instead I want to expose the ability for them to add their function into a dictionary-type object, and when they add it, they just have to supply a list/dictionary of the *additional* arguments, beyond the known common data argument. Then I want to bind their function onto those

Comment: That way it's easy for them to script their functions. In your example, I'd have to add assumptions to the Caller class to always treat the first argument as data (I would just get rid of the overwritten `call` function, that's not what I need). But this should be achievable with `lambda` or `partial` to avoid needing the extra class definition.

Comment: I would have thought you could make this work for your solution but I obviously, along with everyone else, am missing the point. There is no "parsing". You just split it how you want in the init and combine how tou want in the call. Pretty generic.